# Go to another page of flexdashboard on click shiny actionbutton

Tags: user-interface, shiny, user-experience, shinyjs, flexdashboard

I have following code in my `test.Rmd`.

````
---
title: "Test Application"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---

sidebar {.sidebar}
==========================

Controllers
-----------------------
```{r}
actionButton("clickMe", label = "Click Me", class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary")
```

Page1
========================

Page2
=======================
````

Initially, my app is on Page 1. I want to take my app to Page2 on clicking the button `clickMe`. Please help me with this..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `onClick` argument like this:

```
actionButton("clickMe", label = "Click Me", class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary", 
             onclick="location.href='#section-page2';")
```

Comment: nice! FYI: They might be also interested in your solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/pa7Y7RkcJ8M

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. I am using modules so I have to create `UI` with `...` option so that I can pass the `onclick` event from the main app.